# Choose which router-outlet that should be used to render the content of a route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've got a `nav` component which is a menu that handles a bit of route switching, the problem I have is that I can't seem to render the content of the routes because I don't have a `router-outlet` within the `nav` component template.

Instead I would like to render the content of the route in my main app component `core`, but how do I tell angular to use the `router-outlet` in my `core` component rather than in my `nav` component?

Since my `[routerLink]` is inside this template:

**nav.component.html**:

```
<nav class="nav-wrapper" [class.is-toggled]="isToggled" [class.is-hidden]="!isToggled">
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li class="nav-link" *ngFor="#link of links">
      <a [routerLink]="link.href">
        <div class="label-wrapper">{{link.label}}</div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="{{link.icon}}"></i></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

It doesn't want to render the route into the `core` component:

**core.component.html**:

```
<!-- The menu -->
<nav-list></nav-list> 

<!-- The router-outlet which should render the videos component -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**videos.component.html**:

```
<h1>My videos</h1>

<!-- This should render the child views of the videos component -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**list.videos.component.html**:

```
<h1>Videos list</h1>
```

So as you can see I want the bottom snippet to be rendered into the middle snippet which is then rendered at the top, inside the `core` component.

How can I do this?

**The bottom line is that I DO NOT want to have a `router-outlet` in the `nav` component.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I've a similar setup where I've a main layout component:

```
<shellheader (menuToggle)="onMenuToggle($event)"></shellheader>

<section id="main">
    <navigation [menuToggled]="menuToggled"></navigation>

    <section id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="block-header">
                <h2>Header</h2>                    

                <router-outlet></router-outlet>

            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</section>

<shellfooter></shellfooter>
```

Main layout component code:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: "app/shell/main-layout.component.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, NavigationComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent]
})
@RouteConfig([
        { path: "/dashboard/...", name: "Dashboard", component: DashboardComponent, useAsDefault: true }
])
export class MainLayoutComponent {

    public menuToggled: boolean;

    public onMenuToggle(event:boolean) {
        this.menuToggled = event;
    }
}
```

And in my navigation component, I've got some router links (and no router outlet, only using routerlink directive, no child routes defined):

```
    <ul class="main-menu">
        <li *ngFor="#navItem of navItems">
            <a [routerLink]="navItem.route">
                <i *ngIf="navItem.icon" class="{{navItem.icon}}"></i>
                {{ navItem.text }}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Clicking those router links changes the route in the browser, and the outlet in the main component responds to those route changes.

You shouldn't need to have the router-outlet in your nav component. If the routes aren't rendering out to your main component, it's possible that you've not included the required directives in the main component e.g.:

```
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";

...

@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ...]
})
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/P6Bkwy?p=info

Further info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Adding ROUTER_DIRECTIVES to the main app actually did the trick. Kinda frustrating that Angular doesn't tell you when you haven't injected something which you try to use in a template.. This was driving me insane so thanks A LOT!

Comment: I'll throw you a bounty reward when I can :)

Comment: I'm sure I made a similar mistake at one point, definitely a bit of a gotcha. I'm getting into the habit of there needing to be a directive injected if there's any kind of custom html tags e.g. <whatever> on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It seams that you need Component router, consider this Code and Plunker:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { name: "Home", component: HomeCMP, path: "/home", useAsDefault: true},
  { name: "Videos", component: VideosCMP, path: "/videos/..."}
])
```

Than, in VideosCMP

```
@Component({
  selector: 'videos',
  template : `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { name: "VideoList" component: VideListCMP, path: "/", useAsDefault: true}
])
export class VideosCMP {}
```

Full example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/3dnBZEDhpGvVO5aQQswA?p=preview

Comment: This still requires a router-outlet in the navigation component. There must be a way to avoid this.

Comment: True, it requires. Why is that problem?

Comment: Imagine if I have a narrow sidebar to the left that's about 50px wide and covers 100% of the height. Why would I want the content to go inside of that component? I will just mess up the layout, even if placed outside of the wrapper element.

Comment: https://sketch.io/render/sketch56b4a61b03c33.png Is this what you want? If your main Cmp is: MainCmp in html of that Component, you can put <left-sidebar></left-sidebar> and <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: That's exactly what I've done, but it doesn't want to render into the core component anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`<router-outlet>` can be named and aux-routes add components to named `.

This [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mp8pXsWuLt2yAIQgV3p?p=preview) from Brandon Roberts demonstrates it

in `src/app.ts` is an unamed `<router-outlet>` (main) for the normal route and several named `<router-outlet name="chat"></router-outlet>`.

In `@RouteConfig` the `AuxRoute`s are assigned to outlets by the `path:`.

AuxRoutes are still limited.
If this is not what you need @VladoTesanovic 's answer is probably the right way for you.

See [Angular2 router in one component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962955/angular2-router-in-one-component/37967806#37967806) for information about the syntax in the new RC.3 router.

Comment: Doesn't make a whole lot of sense if I have to create every route as an Auxroute for the nav component to being able to find the router-outlet which it should render into. I don't think it will be able to find the router-outlet of the core component either.

Comment: This is why I added "AuxRoutes are still limited" ;-). I just thought I might be helpful to point to them. It's the closes I know to what you asked for in Angula2 currently.

Comment: Really strange way of doing it.. I'll try it out and see if I can get it to work at all. Thanks.