# Angular2 router in one component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I write Angular2 app with router like /main /item .
App have a lot of filter tables/trees/combobox.
I want in /main page open bootstrap modal window (for example call @component modalFilterWindow) and switch content in this window like router.

I can do it like

```
<first-filter-content ngIf="currentFilter=='first'">
<second-filter-content ngIf="currentFilter=='second'">
....
```

but it can be made more beautiful

```
...modal window
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and switch in  modalFilterWindow content by routes, dont change state of main component.

So one component must have own router, not affecting parent router and component.

is it possible?

Comment: Which version of the Angular router are you using?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Aux routes are not working yet with the new router.

Comment: so, its imposible? or i must wait RC3?

Comment: It was possible in the old Router, but since they're rewriting the Router completely, it seems you have to wait for it.

Comment: thx u. i will wait =(

Comment: There are issues with aux routes but basic support should be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can define routes to show components in a named `<router-outlet>`

Route config

```
{path: '/chat', component: ChatCmp, outlet: 'aux'}
```

Named router outlet

```
<router-outlet name="aux">
```

Navigate aux routes

```
this._router.navigateByUrl("/crisis-center(aux:chat;open=true)");
```

It seems navigating aux routes from routerLink is not yet supported

```
<a [routerLink]="['/team/3(aux:/chat;open=true)']">Test</a>
```

*I have not tried this yet*

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9448 for a related issue and a Plunker with an aux-route example.

Comment: We need to add outlet name in path as well?  This doesn't sound great. I should be allowed to route to a component in any available route

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: {path: '/chat', component: ChatCmp, outlet: 'aux'}.  Why should we specifiy outlet here?

Comment: Do you have a spcific use case? Routes are to configire the router. How should it know whete to place components if you don't specify it. If you don't specify an outlet it's added to the default outlet.

Comment: Shouldn't it pick the outlet from URL this._router.navigateByUrl("/crisis-center(aux:chat;open=true)"). V2 router used to do that. In my usecase depending upon user selection  I want to put chat component in primary or aux route.

Comment: Actually I don't know. I didn't experiment a lot wirg aux routes because they are nor yet fully funtional.