# Angular router v3: targeting named outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to route to a named outlet but I am unable to do so. I have modified official angular plunk ( Crisis example to demo).
I have created a "detail" named outlet in crisis-center.component and modified the Admin link to rout to this new outlet
`<a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center/detail:admin']">Crisis Admin</a>`

This is not working. It navigate to component admin but in default outlet I have also tried with navigate method but that is also having similar issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KXOGwX8bW0AYc86OgVdQ?p=preview

I have tried adding outlet in admin route definition as well but still same issue

```
 `{
        path: 'admin',
        component: CrisisAdminComponent,
        outlet: 'detail',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }`,
```

@angular/router : 3.0.0-alpha.7

=======EDIT:======

@angular/router : 3.0.0-alpha.8

I have update the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/Kn4yBi5oytNVcFvUvGLR?p=preview .
Now i am loading admin component in admin outlet specifed

I am getting below error in console when using navigateByUrl.

```
`platform-browser.umd.js:2311 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: 'crisis-center/admin:admin'`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

There is a [fix on it's way](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10003) to land in RC.5

**Original**

`routerLink` doesn't yet support named `<router-outlet>`.
With `router.navigateByUrl()` this can already be achieved but aux routes are not fully supported and have several known issues.

Example:

```
this._router.navigateByUrl("/crisis-center(aux:chat;open=true)");
```

See also [Angular2 router in one component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962955/angular2-router-in-one-component/37967806#37967806)

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/L02zD2BviQ4X6RirivY7?p=preview)

Comment: I have update a plunkr. navigateByUrl doesn't help. I have tried to create cascading outlet as required in my current project.

Comment: The Plunker contains ~20 files. I don't know what to look for.

Comment: Sorry, I referenced wrong plunker in edit. I trimmed down plunkr to 5-6 useful files. File demoing the issues are crisis-center.componenet ( having multiple outlets) and crisis-detail.component plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/Kn4yBi5oytNVcFvUvGLR?p=preview

Comment: I added `()` in `crisis-detail.component.ts` and it seems to work fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/L02zD2BviQ4X6RirivY7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks this worked. i have update plunk to show both (primary and admin outlet) side by side  when we click show admin.  I will try this in my project and hope this will work